# Deepin terminal quake mode not working

Tags: command-line

I have recently installed `deepin-terminal` but somehow when I press `alt+f2` it doesn't turn on quake mode. I see no settings to tweak this shortcut too. Please guide me on as to how can I turn on quake mode? (ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 0):

you have to start the DeepIn Terminal with the following command :

> deepin-terminal --quake-mode

Regards.